# MVC 4 Persistent Cookie is not created, it redirects me to login page.(When FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, persistentCookie: TRUE)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-chrome, cookies, persistence, forms-authentication

**Action in the controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Models.User user, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (user.IsValid(user.UserName, user.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, user.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);        
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect");
            }
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

**user.IsValid function**

```
    public bool IsValid(string _username, string _password)
    {
        bool valid = false;

        if (Membership.ValidateUser(_username, _password))
        {
            valid = Roles.IsUserInRole(_username, "Administrators");
        }

        return valid;
    }
```

**RedirectToLocal function**

```
    private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Practices");
        }
    }
```

**Web Config**

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".PRACTICESAPPCOOKIE" defaultUrl="~/Practices/Index" loginUrl="~/Users/Login" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
```

When FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie gets FALSE in the persistentCookie parameter everything works fine and the cookie is created:

The problem comes when persistentCookie parameter is TRUE, i get redirected to my login page because i validate that the application can not be used by unauthorized users.

If i look at the cookies, the cookie is not created.

It worth mention that the application works fine in localhost, the problem is in the site (I have tested in chrome, internet explorer, and firefox but only works in internet explorer)

Also have tried to do it by creating an authenthication ticket with a persistent cookie and had the same result (redirects when persistent cookie is true)

I am starting to think the problem is in the server where the application is allocated or something with IIS

Any idea ?